# Adding a unique number for multiple same records in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one big table named pub with column NDC that has multiple records where some of them occurs frequently. First I want to create a sequence number for the distinct NDC. for example in (1) the original then in (2) distinct NDC.

```
(1)
NDC:
A
B
C
D
A
A
C
V
B
(2)
NDC: 
A
B
C
D
V
```

sequence number for the distinct NDC in this example (0,1,2,3,4)

after that I want to create a new column to represent the original NDC column by numbers. each of the NDCs now will be presented by unique number. Looking at (1) NDC, the needed column will be

```
newcolumn 
0
1
2
3
0
0
2
4
1
```

for sure while doing this I will be calling the whole table. I don't want to insert each record alone cause the distinct NDC number is too large.

In summary instead of having these strings in NDC column I want to have numbers where the same NDCs have the same unique number in whole table.

Comment: I recommend you learn about ROW_NUMBER() function and Common Table Expressions for SQL Server. Knowing these two things is enough to solve your puzzle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
  ;with cte as
  (Select distinct NDC from YourTable
  ),cte2  as
  (Select NDC,
          rn =Row_number() over (order by NDC ) - 1 
   from cte
  )
   update t
   Set t.NewColumn = c.rn
   from YourTable t
   inner join Cte2 c
   on t.NDC = c.NDC;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00a0c/1)

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
Declare @t1 table(id int identity(1,1),NDC varchar(10))
insert into @t1 values('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('A'),('A'),('C'),('V'),('B')

;with cte  as
(select distinct ndc from @t1),
cte1 as
(select ndc, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by ndc)rn from cte)

select b.NDC,rn-1 rn from cte1 a
inner join @t1 b on a.NDC=b.ndc
order by b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as
(Select t.NDC, t.NewColumn,num.n from Table1 t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY NDC) AS n, NDC FROM Table1) num
ON num.NDC = t.NDC
)
UPDATE cte SET NewColumn = n
```